# Exitting CodeBlocks full screen mode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, codeblocks

How can I exit fullscreen mode in Code::Blocks editor.

I was unable to find keyboard shortcut (using Google and searching in documentation).

I'm running Codeblocks on Ubuntu inside Virtual Box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aha!  Shift+F11 does not work on some versions of Ubuntu.  Use Alt+V to bring up the view menu, use the down arrow to move down to the Full Screen option and press the space bar.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> will do it. I have tested it.

Comment: Nice, I don't have to use the mouse to close the console.

Answer (score 1):

Try **shift+F11**. It works for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :-(  It just tells me that the file does not exist and asked whether I would like to create it.  Do you use any other shortcut keys?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, inside virtual mashine this does nothing for me. :(

Answer (score 1):

Go to search-bar  on start menu or run menu(press <kbd>win key</kbd>+ <kbd>r</kbd>) in Windows 7

Then type "regedit" without quotes, it will open registry editor.

Then click on Console folder, then look for where Program Files_CodeBlocks_cb_console_runner.exe is written.

Then on the right side box you'll see various icon names. > select the one that reads Full Screen > delete it.

Now you console output window will be changed to normal mode.

Run you program etc again to confirm.